# Does $\forall x \forall y\ (x \in y) \lor \lnot (x \in y)$ imply excluded middle?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructive-mathematics

Suppose that we take constructive set theory and add the axiom $\forall x \forall y\ (x \in y) \lor \lnot (x \in y)$. Does this imply excluded middle, or are there still some formulas $\varphi$ for which $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$ isn't provable using this new axiom?

Comment: You are confounding [excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) with "there is a formula $\phi$ such that neither $\phi$ nor $\lnot \phi$ is provable". Even if we remove the faulty use of "provable" and consider "there is $\phi$ such that neither $\phi$ nor $\lnot \phi$", which is expressed as $\exists \phi . \lnot \phi \land \lnot\lnot \phi$, that is **not** excluded middle! It's an outright false statement (constructively and classically).

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that without thinking.

Comment: No problem, I am just pointing it out so that you can edit the question, lest this sort of error spreads. I have seen experienced mathematicians make it (and conclude that constructive mathematics is nonsense).

Comment: If Feferman asked (a special case of) this question, and Rathjen researched it, and 11 people upvoted the answer, isn’t the question worth more than two upvotes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends how much separation is available. If you can construct the set $\{ z \in \{ \emptyset \} \;|\; \varphi \}$ then you can show $\varphi \vee \neg \varphi$. So for theories with full separation, like IZF, you can derive excluded middle, whereas for CZF where you only have separation for bounded formulas, you can only get excluded middle for bounded formulas.

Edit: See Rathjen, [Indefiniteness in semi-intuitionistic set theories: On a conjecture of Feferman](https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Erathjen/Indefinite.pdf) for a set theory with bounded excluded middle, but in which $\mathbf{CH} \vee \neg \mathbf{CH}$ is unprovable.

Comment: Does the end of your sentence ("you can only get excluded middle for bounded formulas") mean that, say, CZF + @James's axiom + $\lnot\text{EM}$ is consistent, or does it only mean that your trick for proving EM doesn't work?

Comment: As far as I can remember CZF with bounded excluded middle is strictly weaker than ZF, but I'll have to think a bit to find a proof or reference.

Comment: In CZF, if $\phi$ is “every set is in one-to-one correspondence with some cardinal”, I doubt you can prove $\phi \vee \neg \phi$ from the proposed axiom.

Comment: I added a reference in an edit. @MattF. I agree, but I don't know a proof offhand.

Comment: @aws We may refer *Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory, Power Set, and the Calculus of Constructions* by Rathjen. According to this article, $\mathsf{CZF}(\mathcal{P})$ with the bounded LEM (which is a subtheory of Tharp's quasi-intuitionistic set theory) has the equal proof-theoretic strength of $\mathsf{KP}(\mathcal{P})$. Hence CZF with bounded LEM is weaker than ZF.

Comment: @HanulJeon Thanks! That works too.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This statement does imply excluded middle in a theory like IZF which has full separation. See https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/exmidel.html for a formalization of this in IZF. The notation there is that DECID $\phi$ is defined to be $\phi \vee ¬ \phi$ and EXMID is defined using a few technicalities but it implies $\psi \vee ¬ \psi$ for any proposition $\psi$.

Comment: Isn’t your answer a proper subset of the other answer?

Comment: I do also agree with that answer - my apologies if overlapping answers are frowned upon.